# Make token/nft transfer within smart contract

Tags: ink, smart-contract, transfer, nft

I want to make token/nft transfer inside smart contracts.
I saw some examples of token transfers and taking that reference, I tried to replicate something similar to that. here is the code.

```rust
#![no_std]

pub use erc721::Erc721;
use ink_lang as ink;

#[ink::contract]
mod erc721{
    use scale::{Encode, Decode};
    pub type TokenId = u32;

    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct Erc721{}

    #[derive(Encode, Decode, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Copy, Clone)]
    #[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(scale_info::TypeInfo))]
    pub enum Error {
        NotOwner,
        NotApproved,
        TokenExists,
        TokenNotFound,
        CannotInsert,
        CannotFetchValue,
        NotAllowed,
    }

    impl Erc721{
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new() -> Self{
            unimplemented!()
        }
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn balance_of(&self, _owner: AccountId) -> u32 {
            unimplemented!()
        }

        /// Returns the owner of the token.
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn owner_of(&self, _id: TokenId) -> Option<AccountId> {
            unimplemented!()
        }

        /// Returns the approved account ID for this token if any.
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn get_approved(&self, _id: TokenId) -> Option<AccountId> {
            unimplemented!()
        }

        /// Returns `true` if the operator is approved by the owner.
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn is_approved_for_all(&self, _owner: AccountId, _operator: AccountId) -> bool {
            unimplemented!()
        }

        /// Approves or disapproves the operator for all tokens of the caller.
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn set_approval_for_all(
            &mut self,
            _to: AccountId,
            _approved: bool,
        ) -> Result<(), Error> {
            unimplemented!()
        }

        /// Approves the account to transfer the specified token on behalf of the caller.
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn approve(&mut self, _to: AccountId, _id: TokenId) -> Result<(), Error> {
            unimplemented!()
        }

        /// Transfers the token from the caller to the given destination.
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn transfer(
            &mut self,
            _destination: AccountId,
            _id: TokenId,
        ) -> Result<(), Error> {
            unimplemented!()
        }

        /// Transfer approved or owned token.
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn transfer_from(
            &mut self,
            _from: AccountId,
            _to: AccountId,
            _id: TokenId,
        ) -> Result<(), Error> {
            unimplemented!()
        }

        /// Creates a new token.
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn mint(&mut self, _id: TokenId) -> Result<(), Error> {
            unimplemented!()
        }

        /// Deletes an existing token. Only the owner can burn the token.
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn burn(&mut self, _id: TokenId) -> Result<(), Error> {
            unimplemented!()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting error on this part
`let token: Erc721 = FromAccountId::from_account_id(contract);`

here is the error

```
the trait bound `Erc721: FromAccountId<_>` is not satisfied
the trait `FromAccountId<_>` is not implemented for `Erc721`
```

here is my contract that is calling the function.

```
#![no_std]

use ink_lang as ink;

#[ink::contract]
mod ebisu {
    use erc721::Erc721;
    use ink_env::call::FromAccountId;
    use ink_storage::{Mapping, traits::SpreadAllocate};
    type TokenId = u32;

    #[ink(storage)]
    #[derive(SpreadAllocate)]
    pub struct Ebisu{
        assets: Mapping<(AccountId, TokenId), AccountId>
    }

    impl Ebisu{
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn init() -> Self{
            ink_lang::utils::initialize_contract(|_|{

            })
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn check(&self, contract: AccountId) -> AccountId{
            let token: Erc721 = FromAccountId::from_account_id(contract);
            contract
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly your error is in instantiating the contract, could you show that part of code? And btw if you are writing ink! smart contracts, I recommend you use [OpenBrush library](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts)

Comment: can you please point out, where is the error? 
I don't have any idea which part is generating error.

Comment: are you saying that, error is getting generated due to missing implementation of trait `FromAccountId` ?

Comment: If the answer is yes, I saw other contracts also doing the same. They were also not implementing that trait.

Comment: I've edited the post, added the code that is calling the contract. 
should I share `Cargo.toml` code too?
@Coreggon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question:

Right now ink! generates a separate structure for cross-contract calls. It has the name `{}Ref` where `{}` is the name of the contract struct. To use it, you need to export that:

```rust
...
pub use erc721::{ Erc721, Erc721Ref };
use ink_lang as ink;

#[ink::contract]
mod erc721{
...
}
```

And use it:

```rust
...
#[ink::contract]
mod ebisu {
    use erc721::Erc721Ref;
    use ink_env::call::FromAccountId;
    ...

    #[ink(storage)]
    #[derive(SpreadAllocate)]
    pub struct Ebisu{
        assets: Mapping<(AccountId, TokenId), AccountId>
    }

    impl Ebisu{
        ...

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn check(&self, contract: AccountId) -> AccountId{
            let token: Erc721Ref = FromAccountId::from_account_id(contract);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

But I suggest you use the [`PSP34`](https://github.com/w3f/PSPs/blob/master/PSPs/psp-34.md) standard for non-fungible tokens to be compatible with other NFT in the network. If all NFT implements the same interface anyone can work with a pre-defined API.

As a variant, you can use compatible to PSP the [trait from OpenBrush](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts/blob/cbb07ba03b9cdd1f0eb897a16a9d6c0d20cf2fa6/contracts/traits/psp34/psp34.rs#L71). You can implements the trait manually, or you can reuse the implementation, or you can use that trait for cross contract calls.

With [wapper feature](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts#wrapper-around-traits) you can do cross-contract calls to any NFT:

```rust
...
#[ink::contract]
mod ebisu {
    use brush::contracts::traits::psp34::PSP34Ref;
    use ink_env::call::FromAccountId;
    ...

    #[ink(storage)]
    #[derive(SpreadAllocate)]
    pub struct Ebisu{
        assets: Mapping<(AccountId, TokenId), AccountId>
    }

    impl Ebisu{
        ...

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn check_balance(&self, nft: AccountId, some_account: AccountId) -> AccountId{
            let balance = PSP34Ref::balance_of(&nft, some_account);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw that in psp34 contract there is no `transfer_from` function. 
how would I create a deposit function for user to deposit into smart contract ? can you give me idea?

Comment: You don't need `transfer_from`. You can read the PSP description. NFT has only one owner. If someone tries to transfer it, we already know from who we need to transfer=)

Comment: `rust
pub fn deposit(&mut self, nft_contract: AccountId, token_id: u32, to: AccountId) {
let res = PSP34Ref::transfer(&nft_contract, to, Id::u32(token_id), vec![99, 99]);
}`                                                                                                                                     so if I create a function like above, transfer function will be called by the function caller by itself?

Comment: No, the function is called by your contract. Your contract sends a cross-contract call, so `ink_end::caller()` is `Ebisu` contract. If `Ebisu` has the allowance to do a transfer, it will be done.

Comment: if the user calls the above function that I have written, will user get the message for accepting the transfer made by smart contract on behalf of the user ?

Comment: PSP34 `transfer` works in the same way as `transfer_from` would, but there is no redundant `from` since we know who owns the token with `id`. So if they have the allowance or own the token, it will be sent.